# QMYSQL driver not loaded on Windows

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am trying to implement a database system in my Qt application. For this purpose, I am trying to use MySQL (with the related `QMYSQL` driver). My class connection-function is written below.

Assuming that `connection` is defined as a `private` class member:

```
private:
    QSqlDatabase connection;
```

we have the following:

```
database::database() : connection() {
    this->connection.addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    this->connection.setHostName(p.database->server_addr);
    this->connection.setUserName(p.database->username);
    this->connection.setPassword(p.database->password);
    this->connection.setDatabaseName(p.database->database_name);

    if (!connection.open())
        this->error = this->connection.lastError().text();
    else this->error = "";
}
```

I get `database::error` with the value `Driver not loaded Driver not loaded` (yes, it's written twice). I've seen here on Stack Overflow that I have to put the driver libraries in my application's path. I've done this and nothing happened. Below is a screenshot of the Qt libraries that are in my path.

[image]

**EDIT**
After calling `QSqlDatabase::drivers()`, I found out that I have the drivers available. Below is the output ( int the *show-more* section of the message-box).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For mingw and Windows: Download the C (not c++) connector from: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/,
then copy the library: libmysql.dll, to the folder: D:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin.
This should solve the problem for the not loaded driver.

Answer (score 3):

1) I assume that you already compiled your qsqlmysql dll. You should have the `qmyssql.dll` in the `plugins/sqldrivers` directory relative to your binary path of your executable.

2) You should also be careful not to mix release and debug dlls (the ones with the `d` at the end).

3) The static method addDatabase should be used this way: `this->connection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(DRIVER, NAME);`

4) Another point: The reason you get the error "twice" (you actually just get two errors combined) is that `connection.lastError().text()` results a combined error message (appended) from the driver and from the connection attempt (see the API more more information about the differences).

5) When i took a closer look at your libs i could not see the non-debug version of `libmysql.dll`. If you run in release mode you must use the release library since the runtime will look for `libmysql.dll` and not `libmysqld.dll`. This will give you this error.

Comment: I had them before in `/sqldrivers/` folder (Relative to my .exe file). I moved them in `/plugins/sqldrivers/` and nothing happens... See my edit please

Comment: The libmysql.dll has to be in the folder of your executable (i guess you did that since the executable should not start if the lib is not in path). In the `plugins/sqldrivers` there must only be the `qsqlmysql.dll`. Did you compile the lib by yourself?

Comment: You have to compile the driver by yourself. It's pretty easy. Take a look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sql-driver.html.

Comment: Which version of libmysql do you use?

Comment: 5.6.19.0 (`libmysqld.dll`)

Comment: Then you have to compile it by yourself. I use 5.6.13 on my home and dev at work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@OnWhenReady's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24223311/1673776), I run the DependencyWalker on the `qsqlmysql.dll` and found that there were missing some dependencies.

```
IEShims.dll
```

I copied it in my path and now it's working!

**As a tip:** run DependecyWalker for this kind of libraries, because, as it's written in the Qt Documentation, QMYSQL driver libraries won't give errors (won't show them).

Comment: As far as i know the dependency comes indirectly from qsqlmysql.dll. It rather comes from the libmysql.dll. The Shims dll should come with the MVSC runtime - at least i think.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't... it's made to dive us crazy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the link for QT5:
http://seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows
=> qsqlmysql.dll and libmysql.dll (and libmysql.lib, if your installation of MySQL has it) are needed

And the link for QT4: 
http://seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt-windows
=> libqsqlmysql4.a and qsqlmysql4.dll and libmysql.dll (and libmysql.lib, if your installation of MySQL has it) are needed

Answer (score 1):

I use msys2 with its qt5 package mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5 (5.8.0-3) and looking at the plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlmysql.dll with the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) reveled dependency on the mariadb.dll, so I installed the mariadb client package:

```
pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient
```

and the dll appeared in /mingw64/bin/mariadb.dll, so I just copied the dll next to my app's exe file and it suddenly worked.

Even if you don't use msys2, you should still look at your qsqlmysql.dll with Dependency Walker and provide the missing dlls to your app. You can install [MariaDB](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-c/) or [MySQL connectors](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) and just copy the dlls from the installed path.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem many times. If you are in

**LINUX**: You need to build it. You need to first install MySQL server then MySQL Client from package manager. then follow instructions in Qt Documentation website [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html). Which is basically these commands:

```
cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql
make install
```

and after the build process finishes, generated plugin will in `$QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/` i guess.

**WINDOWS**: No need to build. Install MySQL and after that you can

1. Install MySQL Connector C (.msi file) and add installation destination folder to PATH.
2. or download the zip file and extract it in somewhere that your application can find.

also, if you have done all above and still doesn't work, you need to install Visual C++ Runtime Libraries. I had this problem in XP and [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) didn't show any missing or incompatible .dll file and after installing those runtime libs my problem was solved. Where you can find them packed and ready? [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Before you test your app, its a good idea to reboot so those changes in PATH and ... can take effect.