# How to make Qt mysql driver in windows?

Tags: mysql, qt, driver

I have built qsqlmysql.so several times in linux. I am totally familiar with the process. But now in stupid windows no matter what I do I can not build it. I am using Qt5.12.1 (latest) and Microsoft VS enterprise 2017 compiler and I have downloaded mysql-5.7.25-win64 and extracted it in c drive.
I can compile my qt projects with VS compiler. The environment Path is OK. there is no spaces in addresses and ...
I proceeded as documentations and used the following command:

```
qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=C:\mysql-5.7.25-winx64\include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:\mysql-5.7.25-winx64\lib\
```

mysql.h exist in C:\mysql-5.7.25-winx64\include  and libmysql.dll and libmysqlclient.dll exist in lib directory. But!!! I am getting this out put after running the command.

```
Qt Sql Drivers:
DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
InterBase .............................. no
MySql .................................. no
OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
ODBC ................................... no
PostgreSQL ............................. no
SQLite2 ................................ no
SQLite ................................. yes
Using system provided SQLite ......... no
TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
```

which shows mysql is still inactive!
I execute this command in powershell.

Comment: You need to have the mysql dll's in either the same folder as your executable or in the search path.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually path contains C:\mysql-5.7.25-winx64\lib where all the dlls are.

Comment: @Eelke It is working now!! I double checked the path environment variable and it was there and I'm sure that I did restart the computer for path change to take effect but I don't know why it didnt work the first time?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually the shipped driver in Qt installation folder is fine and working but it needs to know where mysql dlls are. I recommend using version 5 of mysql because dlls are scattered in different folders in v8. You can have v8 server running but using v5 dlls for the driver. There is no need for compiling qt sqldriver src.

**UPDATE** I've answered another question with more insight [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62611312/6330208)